# Prisma cannot return time > 24 hours

Tags: graphql, prisma

I have project API use Prisma.
Order table has column with Time type and DateTime schema.

```
timeRemain    DateTime? @db.Time
```

When query Order, prisma has some problem.
Case 1: timeRemain has value = 23, API return ok, not problem.

Case 2: timeRemain has value = 25, API return error

"Invalid `prisma.loadManagement.findMany()` invocation:",
"  Inconsistent column data: Conversion failed: Failed to read a MySQL `time` as duration"

Can help me fix this error.